# Gmail smtp with JavaMailSenderImpl

Tags: java, spring, smtp, gmail

I'm using the following code to send an email in Java. I don't get any errors but the emails don't seem to arrive (not even in spam, and I've been waiting for almost a day now)

```
List<SimpleMailMessage> messages = new ArrayList<>();
...
JavaMailSenderImpl sender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
sender.setHost("smtp.gmail.com");
sender.setPort(587);
sender.setUsername("mysecretemail@gmail.com");
sender.setPassword("mysecretpassw0rd");
sender.setProtocol("smtp");
Properties mailProperties = new Properties();
mailProperties.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
mailProperties.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
mailProperties.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");

mailProperties.setProperty("mail.debug", "true");
sender.setJavaMailProperties(mailProperties);
sender.send(messages.toArray(new SimpleMailMessage[messages.size()]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Check did you enable POP/IMAP access to your account, if I remember correctly it must be enabled for SMTP to work. As for java mail properties, this code used to work few years ago:

```
    Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(new Properties(), null);
    Properties props = mailSession.getProperties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.debug", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
```